# How to change First Day of the Week for filter calendars

Tags: servicenow, system-properties

I am trying to change the first day of the week for all calendars in service now.

`glide.ui.date_format.first_day_of_week`
`glide.ui.filter.first_day_of_week`
`glide.ui.date_picker.first_day_of_week`

Those are the system properties I have created already. It works for most calendars, however I am still getting the regular Su-Sa weekend on the calendar that shows up in filters. Is it even possible to change the first day of week for these calendars? The research I've done leads me to those three system properties, but I can't find anything that will let me change those specific calendars.

[image: The calendar I'm trying to alter]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research and found out that this specific calendar is inside List v3. Since List v3 is locked down it seems like changing this calendar is impossible in the current build of ServiceNow.